# Lowercase the second match in a combination of words using Regex.Replace

Tags: c#, regex, uppercase, lowercase

In setting the last name of a person (I know this is a terrible job), I'm looking to lowercase the second match in a combination of any of the following words:
Van, Den, Der, In, de, het.
And repeat this pattern if it happens again after a '-'(combined familiy names).

Wanted results: 
Van Den Broek => Van den Broek 
Derksen-van 't schip => Derksen-Van 't Schip 
In Het Lid-Van De Boer => In het Lid-Van de Boer

I've tried capitalizing the first letters and lower case after ' using the code below. However for creating the above results with Regex is still a bridge to far for me now.

```
var formattedLastName = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(lastName); 
formattedLastName = Regex.Replace(formattedLastName, @"('\w\b)", (Match match) => match.ToString().ToLower());
```

Comment: Your second example doesn't fit the title of your question and what you described in general.

Comment: Do you have a list of names? If you want to match `In Het Lid` to change is to `In het Lid`  you would have to match it first. But how can you tell if this is a name, and `In het holst van de nacht` is not a name?

Comment: Thanks the fourth bird. It's an attribute on a (custom) person entity named lastnames, so I know people will enter their last names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your expected output using

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Globalization;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var strings = new List<string> { "Van Den Broek", "Derksen-van 't schip", "In Het Lid-Van De Boer"};
        var textInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo;
        var pattern = new Regex(@"\b(Van|Den|Der|In|de|het)\b(?:\s+(\w+))?", RegexOptions.Compiled|RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        foreach (var s in strings)
            Console.WriteLine(pattern.Replace(s, m => textInfo.ToTitleCase(m.Groups[1].Value) + 
               (m.Groups[2].Success ? $" {m.Groups[2].Value.ToLower()}" : "")));
    }
}
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/YiCpWW) yiedling

```
Van den Broek
Derksen-Van 't schip
In het Lid-Van de Boer
```

The `\b(Van|Den|Der|In|de|het)\b(?:\s+(\w+))?` regex matches a word from the  `Van`, `Den`, `Der`, `In`, `de` and `het` list capturing it into Group 1, and then an optional sequence of one or more whitespaces and then any word captured into Group 2.

The match is replaced with Group 1 turned to title case (note the use of `System.Globalization.ToTitleCase`) and if Group 2 matched, a space and Group 2  value turned to lower case.

Comment: RegexOptions.Compiled|RegexOptions.IgnoreCase

What does this part do exactly?
Does it mean compile the first case, ignore the second?

Comment: No, it is compiling the regex into a regex object and makes searching case insensitive.

Comment: Situation seemed to change a bit. How would you solve it if all the infixes (Van, de het, een, der, etc) are lowercased, except if it starts with one of these words. And single characters before or after an apostrophe are lowercased

So with the above examples
van den Broek => Van den Broek,
Derksen-Van 'T Schip => Derksen-van 't Schip
In het Lid-Van De Boer => In het lid-van de boer,
'T Gilde => 't Gilde,
Cramen-L'amie => Cramen-l'Amie,
Van den L'isle => Van den l'Isle,
Jansen-D'ancona => Jansen-d'Ancona 
Ebboubola N'na => Eboubola n'Na

Comment: @TimHage Sorry, this is no longer clear. `lid` is not on your list.

Comment: @TimHage If `lid` is not taken into account, you can use [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/BKzf3H/1) and [this C# code](https://ideone.com/PLftUL).

Comment: I only needed to add a ToTitleCase to s in your code, then it works perfectly. Thanks for you help!